# which is the best and easy JSON parsing library

Tags: ios, json, ios6

my next project fully depends on the web. there are lot of requests and need to fetch data from server, I want to know which is the best and easy JSON parsing library for ios 6

Comment: use nsjsonserialization provided by apple. Best and efficient way

Comment: @Baddu: Actually [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) still seems to be way faster. But you'd need to install a third-party library.

Comment: @DarkDust why to use third party if apple provides the way

Comment: NSJsonSerialization will work only on ios5 or later

Comment: @baddu   can you suggest any good tutorial link ?, this is my first time in JSON

Comment: @Deepak this is the good tutorial from raywanderlich   http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/

Comment: @DarkDust, what metrics do you have showing JSONKit is way faster?  All the benchmarks I have seen (and my own testing) indicate it is faster, but not enough to warrant including a 3rd party library for most use cases.

Comment: RestKit is is a better solution for webservise needs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The one that is built into iOS - [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

It is faster than anything else I have used and is super easy to implement.

Here is a simple example (I am using AFNetworking for the request):

```
NSData *responseData = [operation responseData];
id retObj;
NSError *error = nil;
if (responseData) {
    retObj = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&error];
}
```

Comment: @EIJay   can you suggest any good tutorial link ?, this is my first time in JSON

Comment: Apple's class reference page and the example code should be all you need.

Comment: I've been using NSJSONSerialization for years, but just discovered an awful problem:  It allocates NSDecimalNumbers for integer values, and this class has a bug in [NSDecimalNumber unsignedLongLongValue].  If the value has a non-zero high byte, the least significant bits will be zeroed.  It looks like it creates an intermediate double value, then converts to uint64_t incorrectly.  So beware if you're working with JSON with large, 64-bit numbers!

Answer (score 3):

Although NSJSONSerialization is built in library in iOS, it only works on iOS 5 or later.

If you also want to parse JSON prior to iOS 5 then JSONKit is the best library to work with.

It is also awarded as top 10 helpful libraries for iOS on raywanderlich. Here is the link. http://www.raywenderlich.com/21987/top-10-most-useful-ios-libraries-to-know-and-love

You can find JSONKit on Github.
https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit